# Wilcoxon's Signed-Rank Test in the context of 2 algorithms and 1 domain

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, object-detection, f1, shapiro-wilk-test

I'm trying to understand whether my analysis for a problem is in the right direction.

I have 2 algorithms (3d object detectors) that I've applied to the same dataset to obtain TP, FP and FN's for each (using a separate 'optimal' threshold for each one). Now I'm trying to gauge whether their performance is different enough in a statistical sense. So I thought that it's informative to break down the individual ground truths or predictions that make up the TP, FP and FN counts based on the distance each of them is from the origin. So I split the distances into bins B1, B2, etc represented as [0,L1), [L1,L2), etc. for 12 bins. Each bin now has its own count of TP, FP and FN's (TP and FN use GT distance and FP uses predicted object distance). Some bin's have TP as 0 or TP and FP or FN as 0 so precision/recall cant be used directly, but luckily F1 score is a 'robust' summary metric and still works in these cases. So now I get F1 scores for both in each distance bucket that I can subtract to get differences.

A Shapiro-Wilk test gives me a W-statistic of 0.724 and a p-value of 0.0015 that to me means rejecting the null that the data is normal and is backed up by plotting the data to see a very non normal distribution (the data is something like [0.0, -0.0030, 0.0143, -0.0136 -0.0016, -0.0121, -0.0025, 0.0300, 0.1173, 0.1993, 0.1446, 0.0]).

Based on the book Evaluating Learning Algorithms (pp 233), a non-parametric test then seems appropriate maybe like the Wilcoxon's Signed-Rank Test with a two sided test since I'm trying to figure out if they perform different. This gives a statistic of 15 and p-value of 0.2 that based on the alpha value of 0.05 means I can't reject the null that there's no difference between the algorithms.

I guess my question is am I overthinking this? It seemed more informative to compare them this way over a single summary F1 score since I can then look at point counts, etc as a function of distance and tie the analysis together. More importantly though, in the book this test is explained in the context of "two methods, multiple domains" where my case is a single domain (single dataset) where the individual distance bins are highly related to each other. So would that mean this test is actually inappropriate in the way I'm applying it/thinking about it? Would a non-parametric test like McNemar's make more sense?